# Linux broadcast message about a scheduled reboot and how to disable them repeating over and over

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal

If I'm logged into a server for an extended period of time I get a broadcast setting ever hour about the server going to reboot at 2.00am. Is there a way to disable these messages or at least only receive the message once.

Example below

[image]

Comment: What's the output of: `sudo crontab -u root -l` ? It sounds like there's a: [cron job](https://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab) for the [wall](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wall) command set to run hourly. You can modify the cron entry to run daily, rather than hourly.

Comment: No root cronjobs currently present for that server

Comment: What's the output of this: ` ps -ef | grep - i shutdown` command?

Comment: The server has rebooted so the command has no output for now.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/435979/prevent-unattented-upgrades-from-sending-reboot-notifications-to-shell